# How to run covr::codecov() for a R package on Travis CI

Tags: r, travis-ci, covr

I am trying to add [Codecov](https://codecov.io/) support via [`library(covr)`](https://github.com/r-lib/covr) to my personal R package [sesh](https://github.com/nathancday/sesh).

When I check locally the coverage tests run and report without incident:

```
covr::package_coverage()
```

> ```
> sesh Coverage: 68.75%
> R/executeDevtoolDocument.R: 0.00%
> R/sesh.R: 69.23%
> ```

But when it runs on Travis it encounters an error for missing `token`:

```
$ Rscript -e 'covr::codecov()'
```

> ```
> Error in if (nzchar(token)) { : argument is of length zero 
> Calls: <Anonymous>
> Execution halted
> ```

The R CMD check runs successfully on Travis.

The contents of my .travis.yml:

```
language: R

matrix:
  include:
  - r: release
    after_success: Rscript -e 'covr::codecov()'

r_github_packages:
  - r-lib/covr
```

And a link to the most recent [Travis report](https://travis-ci.org/nathancday/sesh).

I have tried to faithfully follow the [covr README](https://github.com/r-lib/covr) for getting set up. And the README says Travis is supported **without needing** `CODECOV_TOKEN`, so I have not tried to pass one yet.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you already enabled the repo on Codecov? That's also mentioned in the README.

Comment: Yes, the repo was activated. https://codecov.io/gh/nathancday/sesh

Answer (score 2):

Following is my `.travis.yml`

```
language: r

cache: packages

script:
- R CMD build .
- R CMD check *tar.gz

r_github_packages:
  - r-lib/covr

after_success:
  - Rscript -e 'covr::codecov()'
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your set up. When I use it I encounter a fatal error because R is not installed. https://travis-ci.org/nathancday/sesh/builds/555137201

Comment: Bit of a surprise as it works for me. In the link, it says the *build language is ruby*. Maybe you have to use simple r not R in `language: r`.  I actually don't know - hence I shared my setting which works.

Comment: That's my mistake on the initial error. I forgot the `language = r ` when I copied your example and [now R CMD check runs fine, but the covr::codecov() still pitches the token erro](https://travis-ci.org/nathancday/sesh/builds/555753265)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the repository upload token to `codecov.yml` avoids the error and successfully runs the coverage report.

```
codecov:
  token: a1c53d1f-266f-47bc-bb23-3b3d67c57b2d
```

The token is found in the 'Settings(tab) >>> General(sidebar)' menu on the Codecov page for the repo (which is only visible once you are logged in).